# Letting MariaDB infer the data type of the generated column

Tags: mariadb, computed-column

How to let MariaDB infer the data type of the generated column?

For example:

```
alter table Customers
add NormalizedName varchar(100)
as (lower(`Name`)) virtual
```

And

```
alter table Keywords
add `Length` varchar(100)
as (length(`Key`)) virtual
```

How to let MariaDB infer that the first column is varchar, and the second is an integer?

**Update**
In SQL Server, you can omit the data type of a **computed column** and SQL Server automatically determines the data type from the expression.

In MariaDB it seems that we are forced to specify data types ourselves.

I am creating a generator, that generates a database from a given JSON file. Since I don't know the data types of computed columns from the given expressions, I have to specify all of them as `varchar`. I wondered if MariaDB has a feature that let's me not specify data type for generated comlumns.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exaclty - as you can see from the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1a841e7256aac333a0c820bf311f32db)  that MariaDB performs an automatic `CAST` of your `LENGTH(key)` function to a VARCHAR - which you can `CAST` back to `INT` if required. What is your end goal? You'll have to **declare** your datatypes - from [here]https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/typeconv-overview.html) SQL is a strongly typed language! SQLite has a flexible type system, but that's another day's work!

Comment: *How to let MariaDB infer that the first column is varchar, and the second is integer?* You obtain strictly those datatype which you have specified. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=237c521eb0395938505532094ddacf21 What is the problem precisely?

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW, sorry about the lack of explanation from my side. Please see the update.

Comment: @Akina please see the updates.

Comment: *I wondered if MariaDB has a feature that let's me not specify data type for generated comlumns.* Noway. But there is a method which allows to determine the datatype. Instead of generated column insering you must create a query which adds this expression as output column and save the output to new table (CREATE .. SELECT). Then check the column type which is used for a column with needed expression.

Comment: Even if you could infer the datatype, what would "0" be?  `INT`?  `TINYINT`?  `SIGNED`/`UNSIGNED`?  `DECIMAL(m,0)`?  `FLOAT`/`DOUBLE`?  Or maybe even "false".

Comment: feel free to [create task (feature request)](https://jira.mariadb.org). Its not a totally mad idea, even if as [~rick-james] shows there are ambiguities. Seek approval and maybe you can contribute the feature yourself.